# android soft keyboard capitalisation

Tags: android, keyboard, capitalization

I am trying to set Android sample soft keyboard to make first letter in sentence  capital. It's the normal behavior of keyboard, but I don't know how to do this((

Answer (score 1):

Must be a bit late to answer, but someone else might need this.

To capitalize the keyboard manually, you have to call your `KeyboardView`'s `setShifted (boolean shifted)` method with desired shifted mode.

Here is an example:

```
private KeyboardView mInputView;
...
mInputView.setShifted(true);
```

But it is better if you let your SoftKeyboard to decide its capitalization mode by checking the attributes of the text editor. For example, emails usually are typed using lowercase letters.
If you look at this sample [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.java), it has a method named `updateShiftKeyState(EditorInfo attr)` which is used to set the capitalization mode automatically based on the initial attributes of the text editor in which the text will be typed in:

```
/**
 * Helper to update the shift state of our keyboard based on the initial
 * editor state.
 */
private void updateShiftKeyState(EditorInfo attr) {
    if (attr != null 
            && mInputView != null && mQwertyKeyboard == mInputView.getKeyboard()) {
        int caps = 0;
        EditorInfo ei = getCurrentInputEditorInfo();
        if (ei != null && ei.inputType != InputType.TYPE_NULL) {
            caps = getCurrentInputConnection().getCursorCapsMode(attr.inputType);
        }
        mInputView.setShifted(mCapsLock || caps != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: great, you save my day

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `android:capitalize` xml attribute for the textview in your layout. Check the possible values for the attribute [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3acapitalize)

Comment: I develope keyboard, the textView may be from different application. I need set this logic in keyboard to capitalize letters in such textViews.